# "You are mentioned in this room in which you are not currently in" - Wrong SO chat notification

Tags: discussion, bug, chat

I have been using SO chat facility since last couple of months. Multiple time I have observed that, suppose I am in one chatroom and I get notification as shown above. When I go to that room I find that that notification was not for me but for some one else.!! This happens because, if two users have similar name (like in my case it was java_developer - mine and java - another user) then I get this notification even though I am not the intended person.
(By pointing like @java, we both are probably referenced.)

I hope I am clear with my question.
Please take note of this possible issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By pointing like @java, we both are probably referenced.

That's correct. It is impossible for chat to disambiguate between two users with the same name.

If your name is `java dev1` and someone else's name is `java dev2`, you will both be notified of replies directed at `@java`. How are we supposed to know which one they meant?

I trust that the devs are hard at work on mind-reading functionality, as that's the next logical step in making this site *more awesome*, but I hear it's still a way off. At least 6–8 weeks, they say.

In the mean time, that's why it's important for people to use your *full* user name when replying in chat. We make this easy for you with the auto-complete functionality.